# Processing latency in different levels of Cache

Tags: caching, latency

Regarding the access time to the cache levels (L1, L2, L3) and RAM,
I encountered with the strange behavior which I didn't find the answer yet,
It would be appreciated if you could help me :)

I started to filling the block of memory in the following manner,
I have the different block size as input, for example 16 Byte, 32 Byte, .... 256 KB,
For each specific block I read memory, count it and write it back. So for example for 1 KB, I have 256 different array of counter (because my counter is int32 and 32 bits = 4 Bytes),
I start with zero for 256 different array of counters as beginning point (let call it array of counters) count it and write it back, I did it for 10,000 counting(0~10000), and do this 10,000 for 100 times and record the this 100 results, get the average and calculate the process time 
(the time calculated like following code)

```
    COUNTERS_MAX = 10000;
    ITERATION_MAX = 100;
    // The Function which each core should do, now is counter (cnt = cnt + 1)
static int
lcore_recv(struct lcore_params *p)
{
    unsigned lcore_id = rte_lcore_id();
    printf("Starting core %u\n", lcore_id);

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifndef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
    struct tableEntry outputTable[ITERATION_MAX];
#endif
#endif

    while(canContinue_)
    {
        //printf("Starting core %u\n", lcore_id);
        //int index=((lcore_id-p->baseIndex)-1+CORE_MAX)%CORE_MAX;
        void * vp;

        struct data * d = p->valueMem;
        FILE* fp = p->fp;

        //fprintf(fp, "Iteration %d ----------------------\n", p->iteration);
        //int index = p->index;

        struct timespec t1, t2;
        for(int q = 0; q < ITERATION_MAX; q++)
        {
            double processTime = 0;
            clock_gettime(1, &t1);
            for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
            processTime = (t2.tv_sec*1e9 + t2.tv_nsec) - (t1.tv_sec*1e9 + t1.tv_nsec);/* nanoseconds */

            //Checks last value of each counter
            int expectedVal = (q + 1) * COUNTERS_MAX;

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
            {
                if(d->value[i]!=expectedVal)
                {
                    if(allOk)
                    {
                        allOk = false;
#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
                        fprintf(fp," Failed : ");
#endif
#endif
                    }

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
                    fprintf(fp,"%d ", i);
#endif
#endif
                }
            }

#ifdef EXCEL_OUTPUT
            struct tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[p->index][p->iteration][q];

            entry->allOk=allOk;
            entry->expectedVal=expectedVal;
            entry->processTime=processTime;
#else
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            if(allOk)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"All counters are ok \n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,"\n");
            }
            fprintf(fp, "*** Time = %f ns \n", processTime);
#else
            struct tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[q];

            entry->allOk=allOk;
            entry->expectedVal=expectedVal;
            entry->processTime=processTime;
#endif
#endif
        }

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifndef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE

        for(int q = 0; q < ITERATION_MAX; q++)
        {
            struct  tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[q];
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", entry->expectedVal);
            if(entry->allOk)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"All counters are ok \n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,"Failed \n");
            }
            fprintf(fp, "*** Time = %f ns \n", entry->processTime);

        }
#endif
#endif
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock_);
        processedCount++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&readWaitHandle);
        pthread_cond_wait(&newIterWaitHandle, &mutexLock_);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock_);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So for each block I did the same test. For example if I have 20 different test points (block memories, like 16 B, 32 B, ....), I will have the matrices with 100 rows and 20 columns of time in 'ns'.
So each column shows the different block size and each row show different 100 test.
Finally I got the average on each column and calculated the process time for each column, the strange behaviour shows up like follow,
[the block size based on Byte and the Y axis is the latency for each process in 'ns', here you could see 3 different cores which run at the same time with the same more or less behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O6uA.jpg)
Whenever I started with small block like 16 B, around the intervals of 50 Byte~600 Bytes I always see this crazy behaviour and I don't know why? (my first question)
So if continue for more than 2.93 MB (which approximately 8 MB(LLC size) / 3 (different core which run simultaneously), we have a jump like follow)
[3 different core run simultaneously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3qq.jpg) 
My second question is that if this jump is make sense, I mean the difference btw LLC latency and RAM latency around 2.5 or 3 times is OK, OR should be more)

PS.My system is Core i7, 3.4 Ghz, L1:32 KB, L2: 256 KB and L3 : 8 MB with 16 GB RAM

Thanks in advance for your help and considerations

Comment: Not body could answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly code (inner loop) as follow exactly btw TEST TEST ON and TEST TEST OFF

```
                       // TEST TEST ON
            clock_gettime(1, &t1);
  47:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
  4a:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  4f:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   54 <lcore_recv+0x54>
  54:   8b 4b 08                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rbx+0x8]
  57:   be 10 27 00 00          mov    esi,0x2710
  5c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
            for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  60:   85 c9                   test   ecx,ecx
  62:   74 1d                   je     81 <lcore_recv+0x81>
  64:   48 8b 03                mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbx]
  67:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
  69:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
  70:   83 00 01                add    DWORD PTR [rax],0x1
            double processTime = 0;
            // TEST TEST ON
            clock_gettime(1, &t1);
            for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  73:   83 c2 01                add    edx,0x1
  76:   48 83 c0 04             add    rax,0x4
  7a:   8b 4b 08                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rbx+0x8]
  7d:   39 ca                   cmp    edx,ecx
  7f:   72 ef                   jb     70 <lcore_recv+0x70>
        for(int q = 0; q < ITERATION_MAX; q++)
        {
            double processTime = 0;
            // TEST TEST ON
            clock_gettime(1, &t1);
            for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
  81:   83 ee 01                sub    esi,0x1
  84:   75 da                   jne    60 <lcore_recv+0x60>
                for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
  86:   48 8d 74 24 10          lea    rsi,[rsp+0x10]
  8b:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  90:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   95 <lcore_recv+0x95>
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  95:   8b 4b 08                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rbx+0x8]
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
            processTime = (t2.tv_sec*1e9 + t2.tv_nsec) - (t1.tv_sec*1e9 + t1.tv_nsec);/* nanoseconds */
            // TEST TEST OFF

            //Checks last value of each counter
            int expectedVal = (q + 1) * COUNTERS_MAX;
  98:   41 8d 7c 24 01          lea    edi,[r12+0x1]
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
            processTime = (t2.tv_sec*1e9 + t2.tv_nsec) - (t1.tv_sec*1e9 + t1.tv_nsec);/* nanoseconds */
  9d:   c4 e1 f3 2a 4c 24 10    vcvtsi2sd xmm1,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
  a4:   c4 e1 eb 2a 14 24       vcvtsi2sd xmm2,xmm2,QWORD PTR [rsp]
  aa:   c4 e1 fb 2a 44 24 18    vcvtsi2sd xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  b1:   85 c9                   test   ecx,ecx
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
            processTime = (t2.tv_sec*1e9 + t2.tv_nsec) - (t1.tv_sec*1e9 + t1.tv_nsec);/* nanoseconds */
  b3:   c5 f3 59 0d 00 00 00    vmulsd xmm1,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # bb <lcore_recv+0xbb>
  ba:   00 
  bb:   c5 eb 59 15 00 00 00    vmulsd xmm2,xmm2,QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # c3 <lcore_recv+0xc3>
  c2:   00 
  c3:   c5 f3 58 d8             vaddsd xmm3,xmm1,xmm0
  c7:   c4 e1 f3 2a 4c 24 08    vcvtsi2sd xmm1,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
  ce:   c5 eb 58 c1             vaddsd xmm0,xmm2,xmm1
  d2:   c5 e3 5c c0             vsubsd xmm0,xmm3,xmm0
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  d6:   74 6a                   je     142 <lcore_recv+0x142>
  d8:   48 8b 33                mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rbx]
  db:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
  dd:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x1
  e2:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  e8:   44 39 2c 86             cmp    DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4],r13d
  ec:   41 0f 45 d6             cmovne edx,r14d
  f0:   48 83 c0 01             add    rax,0x1
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
  f4:   39 c1                   cmp    ecx,eax
  f6:   77 f0                   ja     e8 <lcore_recv+0xe8>
#endif
                }
            }
```

Comment: Mahdi, linear read of data will not depend on latency. You have array of counters, they are consequently stored in memory. Intel CPUs will do hardware prefetching of next counters; and Out-of-order cpu core will reorder instructions to hide latency. So, I guess your benchmark may not reflect real task...

Comment: So what's ur idea, what could I do?
Do u have any precise idea regarding this behaviour?
Thanks for your answer man :)

Comment: What do u mean "Out-of-order cpu core"?

Comment: I wanna know the source of this interfering and remove them in order to guarantee the deterministic access, because it happens always regardless of the system or cores, and more or less have the same shape.

Comment: I mean all modern high-performance high-frequency CPUs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution (they execute several instructions every cpu cycle; order of execution is not the same as in machine code). You can't use "ns" values from this benchmark to get deterministic data for your real code (it will be more complex, less linear access pattern).

Comment: Tnx osgx
What is ur idea  regarding that behaviour? (interval 50B~600B)

Comment: How could I found and remove this behaviour?

Comment: Idea is to get some basic hardware event counters for intervals. It can be easier if you can rework your test to benchmark only single size per run; and it can be useful to make several cycles with the size (one run should run for several seconds at least). Then, use `perf stat` and `perf stat -d` to compare hw counters between two sizes (run 1 for 10; run 2 for 100; compute elementary updates count, get stats on how-many-this-counter-costs-for-single-update).

Answer (score 1):

Your way of testing is not test to measure cache latency (and you have TubroBoost turned on, so there is no constant cpu frequency.).

The latency of caches are known, and are measured in cpu cycles, not in ns (caches runs at cpu core frequency); and memory latency is in cycles + ns, because data must be passed through cache hierarchy (cycles) after it was read from memory (ns, memory has its own clocking).

For example for i7-4xxx (Haswell): 
http://7-cpu.com/cpu/Haswell.html

> Intel Haswell
>
> Intel i7-4770 (Haswell), 3.4 GHz (Turbo Boost off), 22 nm. RAM: 32 GB (PC3-12800 cl11 cr2).
>
> - L1 Data Cache Latency = 4 cycles for simple access via pointer
> - L1 Data Cache Latency = 5 cycles for access with complex address calculation (size_t n, *p; n = p[n]).
> - L2 Cache Latency = 12 cycles
> - L3 Cache Latency = 36 cycles
> - RAM Latency = 36 cycles + 57 ns

What you have now: adding some "count" constants to several counters (yes, it is very probable that compiler was able to optimize inner loop into `d->value[i] += d->count`).

```
       for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
            {
                d->value[i]++;
            }
        }
```

What should you have to measure cache latency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542939/196561

> Widely used classic test for cache latency is iterating over the linked list.  ... This method is used by open-source lmbench - in the test lat_mem_rd ... There are sources of lat_mem_rd test from lmbench: https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/lmbench/blob/master/src/lat_mem_rd.c
>
> the main test is

```
#define ONE p = (char **)*p;
#define FIVE    ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
#define TEN FIVE FIVE
#define FIFTY   TEN TEN TEN TEN TEN
#define HUNDRED FIFTY FIFTY

void
benchmark_loads(iter_t iterations, void *cookie)
{
    struct mem_state* state = (struct mem_state*)cookie;
    register char **p = (char**)state->p[0];
    register size_t i;
    register size_t count = state->len / (state->line * 100) + 1;

    while (iterations-- > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            HUNDRED;
        }
    }

    use_pointer((void *)p);
    state->p[0] = (char*)p;
}
```

So, after deciphering the macro we do a lot of linear operations like:

```
 p = (char**) *p;  // (in intel syntax) == mov eax, [eax]
 p = (char**) *p;
 p = (char**) *p;
 ....   // 100 times total
 p = (char**) *p;
```

As says the man page http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_mem_rd.8.html

> The benchmark runs as two nested loops. The outer loop is the stride size. The inner loop is the array size. For each array size, the benchmark creates a ring of pointers that point forward one stride. Traversing the array is done by

```
 p = (char **)*p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
My goal was not cache latency, I mean the processing time for each specific counting regardless of the size of the block should be logical.
As you can see the figures in the interval of 50 Byte~600 Byte, it is absolutely not, but afterwards it is more or less constant till close to the size of LLC
What do u think about this Behavior

Comment: user176692, what is your OS, compiler (with options) and exact model of CPU? Can you check (and show in update to the question) assembly code of the internal (measured) loop (between calls to clock_gettime)? Can you post full source code here on in internet to allow anybody to check which clock does you use (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, don't use '1' instead of real macro), how the code compiles, how the memory was allocated?

Comment: I did it in new post :) tnx osgx for your follow up ;)

Comment: Still no exact model of CPU (i7-WHAT, just check your /proc/cpuinfo) and no assembler code of inner loop.

Comment: Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Comment: How did you compute "latency in ns" which is drawn on graphs?

Comment: B104=B102/(2^4/4)/10000/1.5^1   ,,,,
C104=C102/(2^4/4)/10000/1.5^2   ,,,,
D104=D102/(2^4/4)/10000/1.5^3   ,,,,   and so on ...
indeed it should be XX104=XX102/(2^Factor/4)/COUNTERS_MAX/BKMG^n   ,,,,

Comment: this time is the total time for counting from 1 to 10,000 ,  so should divided on 10000 because we're looking for single process(which is read memory, count it and write it back), also should be divided on 1.5^1 in first column because the size of block is times to 1.5 in first column, also should divided on 2^4 because I set the size to 16 Byte in first column and 16 should divided on 4 because each counter is 4 bytes :)

Comment: Do u have any news for me :) @osgx

Comment: I did following test but the result didn't see sensible difference,

Comment: 1) Test on the other system with the same specification
2) Put couple of big enough block at the beginning and go on with the same blocks like before , 1 KB, 2 KB, 4 KB, 8 KB, 1.5 B, (1.5)^2 B, (1.5)^3 B, (1.5)^4 B, ... (1.5)^20 B.
3) Put the sleep (5 seconds) Or counting function (fake counting just for wasting time) for fulling the beginning intervals with the function except our main counters and then begin our task like before.
4) Turn off turbo boost for all cores (which are on by default)

Comment: 5) Build the assembly code, attached in the following, between lines with comment TEST TEST ON, TEST TEST OFF, but I didn't get specific point from assembly code.
Another big issue is regarding this average available time which is around 0.560 ns, as our system clock is around 0.294 ns (3.4 Ghz) so read memory, count it and write it back seems take just 2 clock which is no logical :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS,
I use gcc,
my makefile is as follow

```
ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
$(error "Please define RTE_SDK environment variable")
endif

# Default target, can be overriden by command line or environment
RTE_TARGET ?= x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc

include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk

# binary name
APP = Mahdi_test

INC += $(wildcard include/*.h)

# all source are stored in SRCS-y
SRCS-y := main.c

CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS) -I -S$(SRCDIR)/include -I/usr/local/include

# Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line,
# otherwise they are disabled, even if individual optimization flags are specified.
# With -O, the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time, 
# without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time.
# -O3 Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2

# EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O3 -S -Wno-error -std=c99
# After following line do make, go to ./build and run : objdump -d -M intel -S main.o >a.txt
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O3 -g -Wno-error -std=c99

# rte.extapp.mk : External application
include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk
```

CPU :
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              6784.24
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7

All code is in single file (I am using dpdk in order to use the benefits of this library),

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <rte_memory.h>
#include <rte_malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <rte_ring.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define EXCEL_OUTPUT

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#define DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
#endif

#define CORE_MAX        3
#define BLOCK_MAX       20     // BKMG = 4, ~ 168.72 MB
#define COUNTERS_MAX    10000
#define ITERATION_MAX   100
#define Factor          1.5

#define BKMG            4

char* testNumber = "23";


/*
uint32_t sizes[BLOCK_MAX] = {   
                                1*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 2*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 4*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 8*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 16*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 32*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 64*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 128*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 256*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4, 512*Factor*pow(2, 10)/4,
                                1*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 2*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 4*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 8*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 16*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 32*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 64*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 128*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 256*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4, 512*Factor*pow(2, 20)/4,
                                1*Factor*pow(2, 30)/4, 2*Factor*pow(2, 30)/4
                            };
*/
uint32_t sizes[BLOCK_MAX] = {   
                                pow(Factor, 1)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 2)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 3)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 4)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 5)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 6)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 7)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 8)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor, 9)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,10)*pow(2, BKMG)/4,
                                pow(Factor,11)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,12)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,13)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,14)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,15)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,16)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,17)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,18)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,19)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,20)*pow(2, BKMG)/4,
                                pow(Factor,21)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,22)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,23)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,24)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,25)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,26)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,27)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,28)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,29)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,30)*pow(2, BKMG)/4,
                                pow(Factor,31)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,32)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,33)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,34)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,35)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,36)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,37)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,38)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,39)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,40)*pow(2, BKMG)/4,
                                pow(Factor,41)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,42)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,43)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,44)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,45)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,46)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,47)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,48)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,49)*pow(2, BKMG)/4, pow(Factor,50)*pow(2, BKMG)/4,
                            };

/*
char* names[BLOCK_MAX] = {  
                            "1K", "2K", "4K", "8K", "16K", "32K", "64K", "128K", "256K", "512K",
                            "1M", "2M", "4M", "8M", "16M", "32M", "64M", "128M", "256M", "512M",
                            "1G", "2G"
                         };
*/

char* names[BLOCK_MAX] = {  
                            "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10",
                            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
                            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30",
                            "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40",
                            "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50",
                         };

// This struct keeps the inoput parameter for each single core (for 3 cores we have 3 of this struct)
struct lcore_params 
{
    struct data* valueMem;  // This pointer is the address of one sample of data struct which include the address of memorty related to core and the size of that
    int iteration;          // This keeos the number of main iteratiopn, which block of memory now is processing
    FILE* fp;               // This keeps the handler address of opened file for related core, which via that we could write in mentioned file
    int index;              // This keeps the number of core, here we don't use it anymore
};

// Keeps the information regarding the memory which allocates to cores
struct data 
{
    uint32_t* value;    // This keeps the memory address. This memory is allocated independent for each specific core
    uint32_t count;     // The variable 'count' shows the number of 32-bits taken memory.
};

struct tableEntry
{
    int expectedVal;
    double processTime;
    bool allOk;
};

// This thread variavbles is using for coordination btw cores in order to prevent them interfereing each other while checking readWaitHandle and newIterWaitHandle
pthread_mutex_t mutexLock_;

// All slave cores wait here till the signal issues(via pthread_cond_signal(&newIterWaitHandle)) from master core in order to start new memory block 
// Conversely going through newIterWaitHandle goes up here which master core wait till all slave finish their tasks
pthread_cond_t readWaitHandle, newIterWaitHandle;

bool canContinue_ = true;
int processedCount = 0;

#ifdef EXCEL_OUTPUT
//holds all outputs. we save them at the end of work
struct tableEntry outputTable[CORE_MAX][BLOCK_MAX][ITERATION_MAX];

#endif

// The Function which each core should do, now is counter (cnt = cnt + 1)
static int
lcore_recv(struct lcore_params *p)
{
    unsigned lcore_id = rte_lcore_id();
    printf("Starting core %u\n", lcore_id);

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifndef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
    struct tableEntry outputTable[ITERATION_MAX];
#endif
#endif
    
    while(canContinue_)
    {
        //printf("Starting core %u\n", lcore_id);
        //int index=((lcore_id-p->baseIndex)-1+CORE_MAX)%CORE_MAX;
        void * vp;

        struct data * d = p->valueMem;
        FILE* fp = p->fp;

        //fprintf(fp, "Iteration %d ----------------------\n", p->iteration);
        //int index = p->index;
        struct timespec t1, t2;
        for(int q = 0; q < ITERATION_MAX; q++)
        {
            double processTime = 0;
            // TEST TEST ON
            clock_gettime(1, &t1);
            for(uint32_t p = 0; p <= COUNTERS_MAX - 1; p++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
                {
                    d->value[i]++;
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(1, &t2);
            processTime = (t2.tv_sec*1e9 + t2.tv_nsec) - (t1.tv_sec*1e9 + t1.tv_nsec);/* nanoseconds */
            // TEST TEST OFF
            //Checks last value of each counter
            int expectedVal = (q + 1) * COUNTERS_MAX;

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", expectedVal);
#endif
#endif
            bool allOk = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < d->count; i++)
            {
                if(d->value[i]!=expectedVal)
                {
                    if(allOk)
                    {
                        allOk = false;
#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
                        fprintf(fp," Failed : ");
#endif
#endif
                    }
                    
#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
                    fprintf(fp,"%d ", i);
#endif
#endif
                }
            }
            
#ifdef EXCEL_OUTPUT
            struct tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[p->index][p->iteration][q];

            entry->allOk=allOk;
            entry->expectedVal=expectedVal;
            entry->processTime=processTime;
#else
#ifdef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE
            if(allOk)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"All counters are ok \n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,"\n");
            }
            fprintf(fp, "*** Time = %f ns \n", processTime);
#else
            struct tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[q];

            entry->allOk=allOk;
            entry->expectedVal=expectedVal;
            entry->processTime=processTime;
#endif
#endif
        }

#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
#ifndef DIRECT_FILE_WRITE

        for(int q = 0; q < ITERATION_MAX; q++)
        {
            struct  tableEntry* entry= &outputTable[q];
            fprintf(fp," Expected : %d\n", entry->expectedVal);
            if(entry->allOk)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"All counters are ok \n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,"Failed \n");
            }
            fprintf(fp, "*** Time = %f ns \n", entry->processTime);

        }
#endif
#endif
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock_);
        processedCount++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&readWaitHandle);
        pthread_cond_wait(&newIterWaitHandle, &mutexLock_);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock_);
    }
    return 0;
}

// mem_alloc is used in order to release the allocated memory and resize the new memory with new size for it. This function is called for each separate core
static void 
mem_alloc(struct data* valueMem, uint32_t newSize, uint32_t iteration)
{
    valueMem->count = newSize;
    if(valueMem->value)
    {
        rte_free(valueMem->value);
    }
    valueMem->value = (uint32_t *)rte_zmalloc(NULL, sizeof(uint32_t) * newSize, 0);
    if(!valueMem->value)
    {
        printf("Memory Fail\n");
    }
}

#ifdef EXCEL_OUTPUT
void saveToExcelFile()
{
    
    char name[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    strcat(name, "output");
    strcat(name, testNumber);
    strcat(name, ".xml");

    FILE* fp = fopen(name, "w");
    
    // some setting of excel and xml file
    fprintf(fp,"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n\
    <?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>\n\
    <Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"\n\
    xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\n\
    xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\"\n\
    xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"\n\
    xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">\n\
    <DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">\n\
    <Author>m</Author>\n\
    <LastAuthor>m</LastAuthor>\n\
    <Created>2016-06-11T13:00:49Z</Created>\n\
    <LastSaved>2016-06-11T13:01:30Z</LastSaved>\n\
    <Version>15.00</Version>\n\
    </DocumentProperties>\n\
    <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">\n\
    <AllowPNG/>\n\
    </OfficeDocumentSettings>\n\
    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">\n\
    <WindowHeight>7755</WindowHeight>\n\
    <WindowWidth>20490</WindowWidth>\n\
    <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>\n\
    <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>\n\
    <ActiveSheet>0</ActiveSheet>\n\
    <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>\n\
    <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>\n\
    </ExcelWorkbook>\n\
    <Styles>\n\
    <Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">\n\
    <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>\n\
    <Borders/>\n\
    <Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#000000\"/>\n\
    <Interior/>\n\
    <NumberFormat/>\n\
    <Protection/>\n\
    </Style>\n\
    <Style ss:ID=\"s62\">\n\
    <Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#FF0000\"\n\
    ss:Bold=\"1\"/>\n\
    </Style>\n\
    </Styles>\n");

    for(int i=0; i < CORE_MAX; i++)
    {
        // starts a worksheet
        fprintf(fp,"<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet%d\">\n\
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=\"%d\" ss:ExpandedRowCount=\"%d\" x:FullColumns=\"1\"\n\
        x:FullRows=\"1\" ss:DefaultRowHeight=\"15\">\n", i + 1, BLOCK_MAX + 1, ITERATION_MAX + 4);

        fprintf(fp, "<Column ss:Width=\"95.25\"/>\n");
        fprintf(fp,"<Row ss:StyleID=\"s62\">\n");

        for(int q=0; q < BLOCK_MAX; q++)
        {
            char s[10];
            float f = (float)(pow(Factor,q+1)*pow(2.0, BKMG));
            sprintf(s,"%0.3f", f);
            if(q == 0)
            {
               fprintf(fp,"<Cell ss:Index=\"2\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">%s</Data></Cell>\n", s);
            }
            else
            {
               fprintf(fp,"<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">%s</Data></Cell>\n", s);
            }
        }
        fprintf(fp,"</Row>\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < ITERATION_MAX; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"<Row>\n");
            for(int q = 0; q < BLOCK_MAX; q++)
            {
                if(q == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(fp,"<Cell ss:Index=\"2\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">%f</Data></Cell>\n", outputTable[i][q][j].processTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(fp,"<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">%f</Data></Cell>\n", outputTable[i][q][j].processTime);
                }
            }
            fprintf(fp,"</Row>\n");
        }
        
        fprintf(fp,"<Row>\n");
        fprintf(fp,"<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s62\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Mean</Data></Cell>\n");
        for(int q = 0; q < BLOCK_MAX; q++)
        {      
            fprintf(fp," <Cell ss:Formula=\"=AVERAGE(R[%d]C:R[-1]C)\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">0</Data></Cell>\n", -ITERATION_MAX);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"</Row>\n");
    
    
        fprintf(fp,"<Row>\n");
        fprintf(fp,"<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s62\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Standard Deviation</Data></Cell>\n");
        for(int q=0; q<BLOCK_MAX; q++)
        {      
            fprintf(fp," <Cell ss:Formula=\"=STDEV(R[%d]C:R[-1]C)\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">0</Data></Cell>\n", -(ITERATION_MAX + 1));
        }
        fprintf(fp,"</Row>\n");
        fprintf(fp,"<Row>\n");
        fprintf(fp,"<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s62\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Add Latency</Data></Cell>\n");
        for(int q=0; q<BLOCK_MAX; q++)
        {      
            fprintf(fp," <Cell ss:Formula=\"=R[-2]C/(2^4/4)/%d/%f^%d\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">0</Data></Cell>\n",COUNTERS_MAX, Factor, q + 1);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"</Row>\n");

        //end of worksheet
        fprintf(fp,"</Table>\n</Worksheet>\n");
    }
    //end of file
    fprintf(fp,"</Workbook>");
    fclose(fp);
}
#endif

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    mkdir("./Resaults", 0777);

    int ret;
    unsigned lcore_id;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexLock_, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&newIterWaitHandle, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&readWaitHandle, NULL);

    ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);

    if (ret < 0)
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot init EAL\n");
    struct lcore_params params[CORE_MAX];
    char numT[5];
    sprintf(numT, "%d", CORE_MAX);

    for(int i = 0; i < CORE_MAX; i++)
    {


        // Generates some structures to hold information of assinged job of each core
        struct data* commonMem = (struct data*)rte_malloc(NULL, sizeof(struct data), 0);


#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
        char num[5];
        sprintf(num, "%d", i);

        char name3[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        strcat(name3, "./Resaults/");
        strcat(name3, testNumber);

        mkdir(name3, 0777);

        strcat(name3, "/R");
        strcat(name3, num);
        strcat(name3, "_");
        strcat(name3, numT);
        strcat(name3, "Core");

        mkdir(name3, 0777);

        char name2[] = {'/','R', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        strcat(name2, num);
        strcat(name2, "_");
        strcat(name2, names[0]);
        strcat(name2, ".txt");

        strcat(name3, name2);
        params[i].fp = fopen(name3, "w");
#endif

        mem_alloc(commonMem, sizes[0], 0);
        params[i].valueMem = commonMem;
        params[i].index = i;
        params[i].iteration = 0;
        commonMem->value[i] = NULL;
    }
    /*
    printf("sleep ...\n");
    for(int f=0;f<4; f++)
    {
      sleep(1);
    }
    */
    /*
    double p=0;
    for(double f=0;f<1e9; f+=0.3)
    {
      p+=0.1;
    }*/
    
    printf("Starting lcores ...\n");
    printf("RTE_MAX_LCORE = %d\n", RTE_MAX_LCORE);

    lcore_id = rte_get_next_lcore(-1, 1, 0);

    processedCount = 0;

    // Ask each core do the funtion lcore_recv
    for(int i = 0; i < CORE_MAX; i++)
    {
        rte_eal_remote_launch((lcore_function_t*)lcore_recv, &params[i], lcore_id);
        lcore_id = rte_get_next_lcore(lcore_id, 0, 1);
    }
    // For each core do the function for "BLOCK_MAX" times
    for(int j = 1; j <= BLOCK_MAX; j++)
    {
        printf("Iteration : %d\n", j);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock_);
        while(processedCount < CORE_MAX)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&readWaitHandle, &mutexLock_);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < CORE_MAX; i++)
        {
#ifndef EXCEL_OUTPUT
            fclose(params[i].fp);
            if(j < BLOCK_MAX)
            {
                char num[5];
                sprintf(num, "%d", i);
                char name3[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                strcat(name3, "./Resaults/");
                strcat(name3, testNumber);
                mkdir(name3, 0777);
                strcat(name3, "/R");
                strcat(name3, num);
                strcat(name3, "_");
                strcat(name3, numT);
                strcat(name3, "Core");
                mem_alloc( params[i].valueMem, sizes[j], j);
                char name2[] = {'/','R', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                strcat(name2, num);
                strcat(name2, "_");
                strcat(name2, names[j]);
                strcat(name2, ".txt");
                strcat(name3, name2);
                params[i].fp = fopen(name3,"w");
                params[i].iteration = j;
            }
#else
            mem_alloc( params[i].valueMem, sizes[j], j);
            params[i].iteration = j;
#endif

        }

        if(j < BLOCK_MAX)
        {
            printf("%d : New Data Added ----------\n", j);
        }
        else
        {
            canContinue_ = false;
        }
        //Signal cores in order to start new iteration
        processedCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < CORE_MAX; i++)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&newIterWaitHandle);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock_);
    }

    printf("Waiting for lcores to finish ...\n");

#ifdef EXCEL_OUTPUT
    saveToExcelFile();
#endif
    rte_eal_mp_wait_lcore();
    return 0;
}
```

and I run the source run.sh with this command line

## !/bin/sh

./build/app/Mahdi_test -c 0x55 --master-lcore 0