# Is there a better way to generate points on a circle than trying out points in the equation x^2 + y^2 = r^2?

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have seen many apps which draw circles e.g pygame for python, p5.js for javascript. But I cannot find a method to find out points on a circle efficiently. My current solution to the problem involves trying out all the numbers in the square in which the circle can be inscribed.

[image: A circle inscribed in a square]

This can't be the most efficient method to do it. What is the method used at the industry level? Does it involve optimization or is it a whole new method?

Comment: using `x^2+y^2=r^2` is ok if you are rendering filled circle and pies and can be [optimized quite a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61097673/2521214) however for just single pixel thick circle and arcs are better algorithms out there like Bresenham circle, ... or exploiting parametric circle equation with step slightly less than 1 pixel etc or render lines instead ...

Answer (score 1):

A [Midpoint Circle Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) could be used.

And an implementation e.g. in `C` from [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C):

```
#define plot(x, y) put_pixel_clip(img, x, y, r, g, b)
 
void raster_circle(
        image img,
        unsigned int x0,
        unsigned int y0,
        unsigned int radius,
        color_component r,
        color_component g,
        color_component b )
{
    int f = 1 - radius;
    int ddF_x = 0;
    int ddF_y = -2 * radius;
    int x = 0;
    int y = radius;
 
    plot(x0, y0 + radius);
    plot(x0, y0 - radius);
    plot(x0 + radius, y0);
    plot(x0 - radius, y0);
 
    while(x < y) 
    {
        if(f >= 0) 
        {
            y--;
            ddF_y += 2;
            f += ddF_y;
        }
        x++;
        ddF_x += 2;
        f += ddF_x + 1;    
        plot(x0 + x, y0 + y);
        plot(x0 - x, y0 + y);
        plot(x0 + x, y0 - y);
        plot(x0 - x, y0 - y);
        plot(x0 + y, y0 + x);
        plot(x0 - y, y0 + x);
        plot(x0 + y, y0 - x);
        plot(x0 - y, y0 - x);
    }
}
```