# How do I iterate over the outer left border of a circle?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, drawing, pi

I need to draw a circle with a specific range. In my case I need to start from the top and then go down to the bottom of the circle, going over the left outer border of the circle. I need to know the length of each line and the X and Y coordinates. I basically see a circle as a bunch of lines stacked on top of each other where as it goes further down the horizontal line length grows and grows until it reaches the middle point, then it goes all the way back and shrinks and shrinks. Then you have a circle. I need to iterate over each of those lines, knowing their X and Y coordinates from the left side so that I can then do `line_to_the_left(x, y, length)` to draw the circle.

[image]

How would an algorithm taking a range look like that does this? I know that one thing I would need is Pi.

Comment: If your iteration variable is the y (height) coordinate, you can get the corresponding x coordinate via the relation (x − Cx)² + (y − Cy)² = R², where (Cx, Cy) is the circle's centre and R its radius.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Midpoint Circle Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) to see if that will get you what you need.  It's not exactly what you describe, but it may be something you can easily adapt to meet your need.

Comment: there are also better algorithms to render filled circle for example see [Is there a more efficient way of texturing a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61097673/2521214) which does use only basic operations in the main iterations...

Answer (score 0):

You can make loop over integer `Y` values. For center coordinates `cx, cy` and radius `R`:

```
for y = - R ... R:
    hw = (int) sqrt(R^2 - y^2)  //halfwidth
    line(cy + y, cx - hw,  cy + y, cx + hw)  //left and right ends of line
```

Comment: For my use case I need it to be in a `line_to_the_left(x, y, length)` fashion rather than `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

Comment: I do believe that you can calculate line length here having  `hw`