# Drawing a circle to bitmap display in MIPS

Tags: bitmap, geometry, mips, display, mars-simulator

Alright so I am coding MIPS assembly in the MARS IDE. I am trying to draw a circle to the bitmap display with a unit width and height of 8 and a display width and height of 512. I get the general idea and have coded a rectangle. But I was wondering what is the best way to try and code a circle? Say the center is in the middle of the display, how do I code this? Is there a way to know which row and which column I am in? Here is what I have so far.

```
.eqv GRAY 0x999997 #hex value for gray
.eqv BLACK 0x000000 #hex value for black
.eqv WHITE 0xFFFFFF #hex value for white

.text
    .globl main
    
main:
    li $s0, BASEADRESS #save in $s0
    li $s1, GRAY  #save green in s1
    li $s2, BLACK #save black in s2
    li $s3, WHITE #save white in s3
    
    #Initialize
    li $t0, 0 #load 0 into t0
    li $t1, 4096 #load 4096 into t1
    move $t3, $s0 #store baseaddress in t3
    
drawRectangle:
    #if current pixel >= 2048  and <=  3000 draw the color
    li $t6, 1023
    li $t7, 1500
    sgt $t4, $t0, $t6 #If greater than  2048 true
    slt $t5, $t0, $t7 #If less than 3000 true
    and $t4, $t4, $t5 #If both true 1
    bnez $t4, drawPixel #Draw gray pixel
        #False branch
        sw $s2, 0($t3) #Stick black into the shape
        addi $t3, $t3, 4
        add $t0, $t0, 1
        b drawRectangle
        
drawPixel:
    sw $s1, 0($t3)
    addi $t3, $t3, 4
    add $t0, $t0, 1
    b drawRectangle
    
startLoop:

    #test   
    slt $t4, $t0, $t1 #test to see if we have colored all 256 bits
    beqz $t4, endLoop #if we have, end program
      #Write the color to the display memory
      sw $s1, 0($t3) #Shove green into that value
    
    #updates
    addi $t3, $t3, 4 #increment the base address by 4 to point to next pixel
    add $t0, $t0, 1  #Increment the index by 1
    b startLoop  #do the loop again
    
endLoop:
    #End program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: It seems you are missing parts, mind putting the entire thing? please and thanks

Comment: I only ask as I am wanting to learn how you would go about making a square lol

Comment: Look up Bresenham's circle algorithm.

Comment: Im just curious what the baseaddress is

Comment: see [Is there a more efficient way of texturing a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61097673/2521214) for some ideas... if you want just the circumference curve then use **Bresenham circle** or **Mid point** algorithms