# Is cycle count itself reliable on program timing?

Tags: performance-testing, timing, perf

I am currently trying to develop a judging system that measure not only time and memory use but also more deeper information such as cache misses and etc., which I assume the hardware counters (using perf) are perfect for it.

But for the timing part,
I wonder if using purely the cycle count to determine execution speed is reliable enough?
Hope to know about the pros and cons about this decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're proposing measuring *CPU* cycles, instead of seconds?  Sounds somewhat reasonable.

For some microbenchmarks that's good, and mostly factors out the variations due to CPU frequency changes.  (And delays due to interrupts if you count only user-space cycles, if you're microbenching a loop that doesn't make system calls.  Only the secondary effects of interrupts are then visible, i.e. serializing the pipeline and perhaps evicting some of your data from cache / TLB.)

**But the memory (and maybe L3 cache) stay at constant speed while CPU frequency changes**, so the relative cost of a cache miss changes: The same response time in nanoseconds is fewer core clock cycles, so out-of-order exec can hide more of it more easily.  **And available memory bandwidth is higher relative to what a core can use.**  So HW prefetch has an easier time keeping up.

e.g. at 4.3GHz, a load that missed in L2 cache but hits in L3 on Skylake-server might have a total latency of about 79 core clock cycles.  (https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake_X.html - i7-7820X (Skylake X), 8 cores).

At 800MHz idle clock speed, an L2 cache miss is still 14 cycles (because it runs at core speed).  But if another core is keeping the L3 cache (and the uncore in general) at high clock speed, the off-core part of that round-trip request will take many fewer core clock cycles.

e.g. we can make a back-of-the-envelope calculation by assuming that all the extra time for an L3 hit vs. an L2 hit is spent in the uncore, not the core, and takes a fixed number of nanoseconds.  Since we have that time in cycles of a 4.3GHz clock, the math works out as `14 + (79-14)*8/43` cycles for an L3 hit at 800MHz = 26 cycles, down from 79.

This rough calculation actually matches up with the 7-cpu.com numbers for the same CPU with a core at 3.6GHz: L3 Cache Latency = 68 cycles.  `14 + (79-14)*36/43 = 68.4`.

Note that I picked a "server" part because different cores can run at different clock speeds.  That's not the case in "client" CPUs like i7-6700k.  Uncore (L3, interconnect, etc.) may still be able to vary independently of the cores, e.g. staying high for the GPU.  Also, server parts have higher latency outside the core.  (e.g. 4GHz Skylake i7-6700k with turbo disabled has L3 latency of only 42 core clock cycles, not 68 or 79.)

See also [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug) for why/how L3 and memory latency affect max possible single-core memory *bandwidth*.

---

**Of course, if you control the CPU frequency by allowing some warm-up, or for tasks that run for more than a trivial amount of time, this isn't a big deal.**

(Although do note that Skylake will sometimes lower the clock speed when very memory-bound, which unfortunately hurts bandwidth even more, at the default  energy_performance_preference = balance_power, but "balance_performance" or "performance" can avoid that.  [Slowing down CPU Frequency by imposing memory stress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399456/slowing-down-cpu-frequency-by-imposing-memory-stress))

Do note that counting only cycles *won't* remove the cost of context switches (extra cache misses after switching back to this thread, and draining the ROB sucks).  Or of competition from other cores for memory bandwidth.

e.g. another thread running on the other logical core of the same physical core will often seriously reduce IPC.  Overall throughput usually goes up some, depending on the task, but individual per-thread throughput goes down.

Skylake has a perf event for tracking hyperthreading competition: `cpu_clk_thread_unhalted.one_thread_active` - IIRC that event count increments at something like 24MHz when your task is running and has the core all to itself.  So if you see less than that, you know you had some competition and spent some time with the ROB partitioned and trading front-end cycles with another thread.

---

**So there are a bunch of effects, and it's up to you to decide whether it's useful.**  Sorting results by core clock cycles sounds reasonable, but you should probably **include CPU-seconds (task-clock) and average-frequency in the results** to help people spot outliers / glitches.